# Oracle one column contains the other column

Tags: oracle, contains

```
ID  - FILE_NAME
100   SOMETHING_100.TXT
```

The question is simple actually. I want to select rows that contains its own ID in another columns string

Any ideas?

Comment: use `where file_name like  '%'||id||'%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSTR might help; for example,

```
select *
from your_table
where instr(file_name, id) > 0;
```

If ID is a number (looks like it), then add TO_CHAR:

```
where instr(file_name, to_char(id)) > 0
```